# Remedy extracting ticket data (REST, SOAP, API,whatever)

Tags: java, rest, soap, remedy

First of all I'm getting into Remedy and the general properties of the program (the ticketing incident managing app). After some research on the topic I've been able to figure out their most advanced API's are coded in Java and C, although several languages have support based on the previous two (Ruby, PHP, .Net etc...) [DOC link](https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-17512)

My goal is to fetch data from Remedy through a webserver (perhaps using Java or whatevs) and fetch the number of tickets resolved by each team.

Question #1: I've read the code examples to fetch info [code example](https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-17514) can you guys provide any hints on the output of these? (I'm asking instead of just testing because I still don't have the keys and ID's to access the local Remedy program, hence I'm unable to test...)

Question #2: I've signed up for the trial in the Remedy page. I can get a good look n feel at the program... but is there a way I can get access to that dummy data through an API (for testing purposes)

Question #3: Is there a way to access the data through REST or SOAP? My googling says no unless I have some 3rd party addons or something like that, but I was hoping you guys could shed a little more light.

Apologies for my relatively vague questions, I'm still not sure what I'm dealing with and all documentation seems big and scary (lots of acronyms and whatnot)
Thanks and it's a pleasure to finally be here. (been a long time lurker but first time posting : D )

Comment: It's hard to see what would be the "correct" answer to this question. I recommend editing your question or splitting it into several questions, so that each question is clear and concise. As it is now, your question might get removed.

Comment: I can't post a new question (due to the 90 minute restriction) I'll try editing this one. But the main thing I'm trying to ask is if there's some test environment I can use the API with some dummy data.